# Calculate distance between two points using pointers and structures C++, Segmentation Fault issue

Tags: c++, bash

Here I have my code to calculate the distance between the user inputted points, and the `calculateDistance` function should take in two pointers, I feel like I had it setup right, but when I run the code I get this error: `bash: line 12: 25372 Segmentation fault      $file.o $args`

Code:

```
struct Point{
    float x;
    float y;
};

float calculateDistance(struct Point *p1, struct Point *p2){
    float *fx, *fy;

    *fx = (*p1).x - (*p2).x;
    *fy = (*p1).y - (*p2).y;
    return sqrt((*fx * *fx) + (*fy * *fy));

}

int main()
{
    struct Point *p1, *p2, q, w;
    p1 = &q;
    p2 = &w;
    //float distance;

    cout << "Enter coordinate for p1x: " << endl;
    cin >> (*p1).x;
    cout << "Enter coordinate for p1y: " << endl;
    cin >> (*p1).y;

    cout << "Enter coordinate for p2x: " << endl;
    cin >> (*p2).x;
    cout << "Enter coordinate for p2y: " << endl;
    cin >> (*p2).y;

    //distance = calculateDistance(*p1, *p2);

    cout << "Distance between points: " << calculateDistance(p1, p2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it segfaults because you're doing pointer arithmetic in the calculateDistance() function.

Comment: This `*fx * *fx` is bad, really bad. Adding parentheses may help.

Comment: If you are doing this for practice, ignore me. If not you can do all of this without using any pointers.

Comment: If you are programming in C++, you need a better reference book.  In C++, you don't need the `struct` keyword when declaring variables or function parameters.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `p1` or `p2`.  You can call `calculateDistance(&q, &w)`.

Answer (score 0):

One fault is in function `calculateDistance`. Please change it as

```
float calculateDistance(struct Point *p1, struct Point *p2){
    float fx, fy;

    fx = (*p1).x - (*p2).x;
    fy = (*p1).y - (*p2).y;
    return sqrt((fx * fx) + (fy * fy));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm new to using pointers and don't fully understand them, is there a quick explanation you could give me as to why I didn't need the * on the fx, and fy variables?

Comment: @Dturley When you declare `float *fx, *fy` then pointers are declared but memory is not allocated to store values. Since `fx` and `fy` were used locally you could declare them as local variable. Another option was using declaration like `float *fx = new float()`. But then you had to delete them after use.

Comment: In C++, you don't need the `struct` keyword in the parameters.  The preferred method to pass the parameters is by constant reference.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yea `struct` is not must but I just maintained the way it was in OP. Constant reference is certainly better option in scenario of OP.